# How can I run Azure TTS on iOS

Tags: reactjs, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I have used the azure microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk for text-to-speech approach in react. In the application I need to play the audio (text) without any user intervention. I am well aware of the constrain iOS has in place regarding playing of audio. Hence I need to play "player" ([See sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/synthesis.html#L341)) On the first button click in mute (zero volume). However if I try to reuse the player I get errors

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'duration' property on 'MediaSource': The 'updating' attribute is true on one or more of this MediaSource's SourceBuffers.
```

Please do help in suggesting an approach which allows me to play the audio on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working on iOS 14.6 using the speakTextAsync API. Give this a try.

```js
    // status fields and start button in UI
    var phraseDiv;
    var resultDiv;
    var startSpeakTextAsyncButton;

    // subscription key and region for speech services.
    var subscriptionKey, serviceRegion;
    var authorizationToken;
    var SpeechSDK;
    var synthesizer;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

      startSpeakTextAsyncButton = document.getElementById("startSpeakTextAsyncButton");
      subscriptionKey = document.getElementById("subscriptionKey");
      serviceRegion = document.getElementById("serviceRegion");
      phraseDiv = document.getElementById("phraseDiv");
      resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv");

      startSpeakTextAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = true;
        phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

        // if we got an authorization token, use the token. Otherwise use the provided subscription key
        var speechConfig;
        if (subscriptionKey.value === "" || subscriptionKey.value === "subscription") {
          alert("Please enter your Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech subscription key!");
          startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
          return;
        }
        speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey.value, serviceRegion.value);

                speechConfig.setProperty(SpeechSDK.PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_TranslationVoice, "en-US");
        synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

                let inputText = phraseDiv.value;
        synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
                    inputText,    
          function (result) {
            startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
          
            if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
              resultDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis finished";
            } else if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.Canceled) {
              resultDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis failed. Error detail: " + result.errorDetails;
            }

            window.console.log(result);

            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
          },
          function (err) {
            startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "Error: ";
            resultDiv.innerHTML += err;
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "\n";
            window.console.log(err);

            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
          });
      });

      if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
        SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;

        document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk@latest/distrib/browser/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle-min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
  <!-- <uidiv> -->
  <div id="warning">
    <h1 style="font-weight:500;">Speech Recognition Speech SDK not found (microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js missing).</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content" style="display:none">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><h1 style="font-weight:500;">Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</h1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started" target="_blank">Subscription</a>:</td>
        <td><input id="subscriptionKey" type="text" size="40" value="subscription">subscription</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Region</td>
        <td><input id="serviceRegion" type="text" size="40" value="region"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><button id="startSpeakTextAsyncButton">Start text to speech</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Input Text</td>
        <td><textarea id="phraseDiv" style="display: inline-block;width:500px;height:200px">(INPUT TEXT HERE)</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Result</td>
        <td><textarea id="resultDiv" style="display: inline-block;width:500px;height:100px"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However as mentioned, I need to use the player provided by microsoft stt, as I need to detect the end of audio clip to use another function. Hence I need that the player is used